# ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

My mind is boggled here - There is an Add method on ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
However if I use it, it throws a "Read Only" error message. My research on the issue has shown that we cannot add connections strings programatically at runtime to the app.config. There is a workaround for this using reflection to set the ReadOnly flag to false

Here is the example with reflection:

```
 public static void AddConnectionString(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString,string Name)
    {
        try
        {
            typeof(ConfigurationElementCollection).GetField("bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings, false);
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(Name, connectionString.ConnectionString));
            EventLogger.LogEvent("Added ConnectionString",1);
            ProtectConnectionStrings();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLogger.LogError(ex.Message,(int)EventLogger.Events.GeneralException);
        }

    }
```

But none of this makes sense to me. I want to store conStrs in the app.config so I can encrypt them. I need users to be able to add them to the app.config at runtime. What is the standard way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app.config file is not supposed to be edited by the application. One way to tell that's the case is to think about where it is located - next to the executable file in a folder that (by default) is not writeable by the user or the user's apps (program files).

I would say if it is something the user is modifying, it should be stored in settings.

Alternatively, you can create custom config files and use the same System.Configuration stuff to access it. But it is a bit unwieldy and I'm not sure what you'd get out of it over the regular settings files.

Comment: This is the correct approach. If you're planning on encrypting the strings anyways then there's no reason to not use a different settings file.

Comment: I'm not arguing with that logic - But why provide an Add method to something that is meant to be readonly. That doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: It's just that the default config file you're accessing there is read-only. The same classes can be used to access other config files (when those classes are instantiated differently) and those are not read-only.